# Visual studio designer property window vs designer file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, devexpress, designer

I have a problem with my visual studio GUI designer. The designer shows different values from my .designer.cs file. For example, item simpleButtonPrint, in the designer I have the following properties:

```
// 
        // simpleButtonPrint
        // 
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(204)))), ((int)(((byte)(204)))), ((int)(((byte)(204)))));
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        this.simpleButtonPrint.ButtonStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.Flat;
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("simpleButtonPrint.Image")));
        this.simpleButtonPrint.ImageLocation = DevExpress.XtraEditors.ImageLocation.MiddleCenter;
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1146, 640);
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(15);
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Name = "simpleButtonPrint";
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 98);
        this.simpleButtonPrint.TabIndex = 9;
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Text = "simpleButton4";
        this.simpleButtonPrint.Click += SimpleButtonPrint_Click;
```

In my designer.cs file, the size is 98, 98. In my properties window from visual studio the size is 131, 121. See the screenshot below:

[image: Visual studio properties window]

Same button, on another machine:
[image]

The problem is when I make any change in the GUI designer, it modifies my designer.cs file as how it is in the GUI designer. It should be a problem with my visual studio, as when my coworker gets the same version from TFS, he does not have the same problem. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: the designer.cs file is meant to be changed when you change properties of control from the designer view. the code in the designer.cs file gets executed and controls are initialized and placed on the form at turn time as per the code written there. To confirm with coworker can you ask him/her to change some thing in designer view and save the form and along with designer.cs?  Either it should ask to checkout the file or automatically checkout the file and make changes to the designer.cs file.

Comment: I have edited my post, with a screenshot from the same user control properties window, but on a different machine. On the other machine it's showing the correct size (98,98). Everything works fine until I modify it on my machine.

Comment: The two computers have different graphic DPI settings.  But there are other properties different, too:  Location, Margin, etc.

Comment: You should point out that you're using DevExpress controls, not Windows Forms native controls. This kind of controls has special behavior sometimes, usually determined by other related controls. Try to make a new empty project and reproduce this issue.

Comment: What happens if you change to 98;98 on your machine?

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech, I changed the scaling mode to DPI and now everything works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I changed the scaling mode from Font to DPI, now everything works fine.